# Laravel - How can I autofill a text input in a form with the address tied to the selected customer's id?

Tags: mysql, laravel, input

This is in my `ordered.blade.php` file. I essentially want to make it to where when I select a customer from the drop down it autofills the address tied to the customer's id. But since it's very hard to find any documentation on this, I've become stuck. Would appreciate any amount of help. Thanks!

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="customerId">Customer Name:</label>
      <select onchange="customerId(this.value)" name="customerId" class="form-control">
        <option>Choose A Customer</option>
        @foreach ($customers as $customer)
          <option name="customerId" id="customerId" value="{{$customer->id}}{{$customer->address}}">{{$customer->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="shiptoAddress">Ship-To Address (Full Address):</label>
      <input name="shiptoAddress" class="form-control" id="shiptoAddress" placeholder="Ship-To Address">
    </div>
```

This is my function in my OrderController for creating a new order:

```
    /*Create Order*/
    public function create( Request $data){
        $order = new Order;
        $order->customerId = $data->customerId;
        $order->save();
        return redirect('orders');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a JavaScript function but it wasn't included in this code snippet, so I changed the function to do what you're asking. If it was doing something, you can add it to the new function.

So basically the first thing I did was rearrange some ids. You have an id set on your option tag which is inside a loop which will create elements with the same id for each customer.

The next thing I did was alter the value you had set for your options as it looked like multiple values were trying to be stored, so instead I used the entire customer object (which will be stored as a string).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="customer-select">Customer Name:</label>
    <select id="customer-select" onchange="selectCustomer()" name="customer-select" class="form-control">
        <option value="default">Choose A Customer</option>
        @foreach ($customers as $customer)
            <option value="{{ $customer }}">{{$customer->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="shiptoAddress">Ship-To Address (Full Address):</label>
    <input name="shiptoAddress" class="form-control" id="shiptoAddress" placeholder="Ship-To Address">
</div>
```

By setting the entire customer object as the value of the option, you will have access to any other parts of the customer should you need to do something with them in the future (ie. use the id of the customer to do something else).

Now for the JavaScript, I used raw JavaScript (you can change it to jQuery if you have it) to get the value of your `Customer Select` and apply it to your `Address Input`

Then I used JavaScript to get the value of your select statement and made it the value of your input field. The `JSON.parse(...)` call is parsing the customer string (as previously mentioned) into a usable JavaScript object.

```
<script>
    function selectCustomer() {
        let select = document.getElementById('customer-select');
        let ship_to_address = document.getElementById('shiptoAddress');

        if(select.value === 'default') {
            ship_to_address.value = '';
        } else {
            ship_to_address.value = JSON.parse(select.value).address;
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the future, if you have multiple keys within your `$customer->address`, you could use the same approach to setting different values of separated inputs for each piece of your address. For example:

```
...
    let address = JSON.parse(select.value).address;
    street_1.value = address.street_1;
    city.value = address.city;
...
```

Comment: Did just realize one issue, it submits the Ship-to address to the DB but doesn't submit the customer name. Trying to tinker with it to get it working but was wondering if you had any tips.

Comment: @DevMatt You should be able to combat that issue in your controller using `json_decode(..., true);` around the "customer-select" form name we are passing through that contains the entire customer object. This will turn the string into an array We could then use this to get the customer's name to pass to the DB. If you'd like, I can direct you further if you post the method responsible for storing your resource.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "method for storing your resource" though.

Comment: @DevMatt I just mean the function responsible for storing the form data in your table, typically this is in a `Controller` and a function called: `store() {...}`

Comment: Let me add the controller to my question. I don't have a store function though.

Comment: @DevMatt That function is perfect. Anyways, can you please try `$order->customerId = json_decode($data->get('customer-select'), true)['id'];`

Comment: That function does work! Thank you, thank you, thank you!! You've have really been a big help!